# Is Spark good for processing data from sql db in a job? How to avoid processing the same data in the job?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a problem and I wonder if spark is a good tool to solve it:

There is  sql db. I want to process data from such table:

**Orders** Table:

| id | product | date |

I would like to create "processing job" which can scan all records and save to other db/file. 
Ultimately, I would like to have several features/tables in the database/file (for example, **the older product orders**, **the number of orders for a given month**).

So, the target database/file will contain the ordersForGivenMounths table with the values: September: 150 (orders with same id), October: 230 ... etc.

Tables in the database will be expanded. I have given only two examples.

1. Can it be done at Spark? Is it a good tool for this type of task?
2. Can I create jobs in Spark that will process the sql database every given period of time?
3. New records will be constantly added to the source sql database. Is it possible to configure Spark so that **it does not process data that it has processed earlier and already pushed into the target database/file** earlier?

I was looking for tutorials/docs but most are introductions without specific solutions.

Comment: Is the target Apache Hive et al, or a nother DB such as mySQL, ORACLE? It's a little vague.

Comment: It is Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: transforming from the same sql server db to another or within same db?

Comment: it's not planned yet. I would like to find best solution. It can be different target db (such a cassandra)

Comment: Think you need to edit question to be more epecific

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use spark streaming with custom receivers, and you can add some logic at receiver. [receiver]http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html